# Can I get wmode parameter from Flash object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a site that includes Flash-based third party ads.  Some of these ads do not have a wmode parameter set, and so when we pop up an overlay from our site, the ad blocks it or appears on top of it.  We do not have the ability to insert wmode parameters into the ads.

Is there a way to determine which ads do not have that wmode parameter set (i.e. get the wmode value for each ad), so I can hide those ads when we pop up an overlay?  The ad sales team has already specified that they do not want to hide the compliant ads in those situations, so I need to hide only those ads that would block our overlays.

Note: I am using jQuery Colorbox for the overlays, if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

You can something like this.

```
$('object:has(param[wmode])').each(function(){
       var wmode = $(this).attr('wmode');
 });
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the value of that wmode parameter?  That way if the ad has say wmode=window (the default) it will not be included in that list.